# How to implement logout in a Node.js and Express application with Auth0?

Tags: node.js, express, auth0

I have a Node.js and Express server, and I'm using Auth0 for authentication. How can I implement logout when the client visits the "/exit" route? Below is my code:

`app.js`

```
const { auth, requiresAuth } = require('express-openid-connect');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

const config = {
    authRequired: false,
    auth0Logout: true,
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL || `http://localhost:${port}`,
    clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    issuerBaseURL: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}`,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    routes: {
        login: false,
    },
};

app.use(auth(config));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.user = req.oidc.user;
    next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'home.html'));
});

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'login.html'));
});

app.get('/exit', requiresAuth(), (req, res) => {
    try {
        /* Logout
        req.logout();
        req.oidc.logout();
        */
        res.redirect('/login');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during logout:", error);
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

I attempted to logout using:
`req.logout(); req.oidc.logout();`

But I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: req.logout is not a function || TypeError: req.oidc.logout is not a function.

Any suggestions on how to properly implement logout in this setup? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This line attaches `/login`, `/logout`, and `/callback` routes to the baseURL, so you don't need to add them:

```js
app.use(auth(config));
```

You should just be able to add a button that calls `/logout`. For example, in `views/index.pug`:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}, #{user.name}!
  form(method='GET' action='/logout')
    button(type='submit') Logout
```

Comment: I need to use the /exit route, how could I achieve this?

Comment: Here's an example of a custom logout route: https://github.com/auth0/express-openid-connect/blob/master/examples/custom-routes.js

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's configured to logout on a route different from /logout:

```
app.get('/exit', requiresAuth(), (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.oidc.logout({
      returnTo: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during logout:", error);
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});
```